# Simple plot with TIkZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

I was wondering whether someone knows how to do the graph on the right. I just know how to do very simple graphs.

Is there a way to put shaded balls and graphs in the same figure?[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I just need some hint on how to do it..I dont need the full picture. For instance, I ve just learnt how to do dotted lines :/

Comment: Please, show us, what you try so far!

Comment: Hello, I'm looking for some hints because I dont know how to start doing it :)

Comment: For a plot, you can see start with something [like this](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/ac-drive-voltage/), while for shading circles, you may `\usetikzlibrary{shadings}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help of the `intersections` library:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, draw, solid, fill=gray, inner sep=1.6pt,
              node contents={}},
                        ]
\begin{axis}[name=plot1,
declare function = {f(\x)=0.5*(x-2)^3-0.2*x+2;},% actual function is unknown
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$\phi_l(x)$},
    xtick=\empty, 
    xmin=0, xmax=4.2,
    ymin=0, 
    restrict y to domain=0:4.4,
    no marks, samples=1000, domain=0:4,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},
    clip=false
            ]
\addplot+[thick,name path=P]{f(x)};
%
\path[name path=A]  (0,1) -- (4,1);
\path[name path=B]  (0,2) -- (4,2);
\path[name path=C]  (0,3) -- (4,3);
\path[name path=D]  (0,4) -- (4,4);
%
\path[name intersections={of = P and A, by=x1}];
\path[name intersections={of = P and B, by=x2}];
\path[name intersections={of = P and C, by=x3}];
\path[name intersections={of = P and D, by=x4}];
%
\draw[densely dashed, very thin] 
    (0,1) -| (x1 |- 0,0) node[dot] 
    (0,2) -| (x2 |- 0,0) node[dot]
    (0,3) -| (x3 |- 0,0) node[dot]
    (0,4) -| (x4 |- 0,0) node[dot];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you like to have shadowed dot nodes, than you need to modify `dot` style to:

```
dot/.style = {circle, draw, solid, semithick,
              left color=gray!10, right color=gray!90, inner sep=1.6pt,
              node contents={}},
```

In this case the diagram is:

[image]

Comment: This is not my question, but could you explain to me the logic behind the syntax of the vertical lines? `(x4 |- 0,0)` is not something I have seen before.

Comment: @MarkusG., that is orthogonal coordinate, determined by intersections of the vertical line through `x1` and horizontal line through coordinate origin `0,0`. It determine projection `x1` onto `x` axis.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know you could do that. But this is a very helpful piece of information. (It also proves, yet again, that even the seemingly most trivial "do this for me"-tikz questions can be quite educational.)

Comment: @MarkusG., for more information about this coordinates see Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, section *13.3.1 Intersections of Perpendicular Lines*, page 144 (v3.1.9a).

Comment: Not quite related to the question though, the π pt border seems very pleasing !